# Shell script won't run cd command

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have a text-based game, Colossal Cave Adventure, that I would like to launch with a shell script instead of opening the terminal and typing `cd ~/Desktop/CCA` and `./Adventure`. The code I am trying to use is this:

```
#! /bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e 'cd ~/Desktop/CCA/; ./Adventure'
```

and the message i receive is this:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process `cd` (No such file or directory)
```

with options to change profile preferences or relaunch the process. I have also tried using the absolute path instead of `~/`, and all of my file names are correctly spelled and point to the right place. What is wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`cd`  is a shell builtin. you should use this:

```
#! /bin/bash
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/username/Desktop/CCA/ -e './Adventure'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that `cd` wasn't a command.

Comment: `cd` certainly *is* a command! It's what is known as a [shell builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands), as [Hastur's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/473277/22949) correctly states. Shell builtin commands are often called "shell builtins" or "builtins" for short, but they are absolutely commands. What `cd` is not is an *external command*. Ubuntu has no `cd` *program* (and [if it did, running it still wouldn't have the effect of changing the directory in the shell from which you ran it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38808/11938)). @Giaphage47

Answer (score 12):

The error

`Failed to execute child process "cd" (No such file or directory)`

arises because  `cd` is one of the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` and not an executable that you physically find on your Hard Disk.

To run it or the others `built-in` commands in you script you need to pass all the line to a `bash` invocation

```
 gnome-terminal -e '/bin/bash -c "cd ~/Desktop/CCA/; ./Adventure" '
```

If there are no other internal command that you have to execute you can set the working directory for the `gnome terminal`, as just answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/473278/196535):

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/username/Desktop/CCA/ -e './Adventure'
```

---

**Ad nauseam**: there are some alternatives:

If you are just in a terminal you can either do

- an `alias` like
  `alias Star_My_Game="cd ~/Desktop/CCA; ./Adventure "`
  and put it in your `.bashrc` or in `~/.bash_aliases` so that you will be able to run with the single command `Start_My_Game` in each shell you will be (It's more cosy to choose a simpler/short name than Start_My_Game...)
- or a script that you can make executable (`chmod u+x MYscript`) and put in your `path` (tipically `~/bin` is a good candidate).

I suppose you can put a link on your desktop that execute the terminal and modify the starting behaviour. [From gnome help](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-custom-command.html.en)

1. Select Edit ▸ Profile Preferences ▸ Title and Command.
2. Check Run a custom command instead of my shell.
3. In the text box, type the command or the desired shell.
4. The command will be passed to the terminal exactly as you write it,
   including any arguments that you specify. Environment variables will
   be inherited from the terminal as it is a child process of the
   terminal.

   Open a new Terminal tab or window to see how the custom shell or
   command executes

Comment: But the point was to launch from a shell script, and not have to open a terminal window.

Comment: If you want to launch from a script is enough an `alias` (more cosy) or a script in your ~/bin directory, without to launch a new terminal

Comment: Answer updated just in case you need again: it's possible to pass `cd` but you need to pass it to `bash`. Give it a check :) –